# selenium connection error firebox java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

code is just  opening firefox and after that it's  not opening the given url. getting exception:-**org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:**

**Code:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class AzurePrice {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int i=0,j=0;
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        //Thread.sleep(5000L);
        driver.get("https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("create-virtual-machines")).click();
        String[] options = driver.findElement(By.name("region")).getText().split("\n");
        //options.length;
        driver.findElement(By.name("region")).click();
        Select se = new Select((WebElement) driver);
        for(i=0;i<=options.length;i++)
        {
            se.selectByIndex(i);
            driver.findElement(By.name("operatingSystem")).click();
            se.selectByValue("windows");
            driver.findElement(By.name("type")).click();
            se.selectByValue("os-only");
            driver.findElement(By.name("tier")).click();
            se.selectByValue("standard");

            driver.findElement(By.id("radio-one-year-987a88d8-f8fa-4b6d-956a-7c0db87f3b92")).click();
            String[] options1 = driver.findElement(By.id("size")).getText().split("\n");
            for(j=0;j<options1.length;j++)
            {
                se.selectByIndex(j);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to download the `geckodriver.exe` and the set the `System.property()` by `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "pathTogeckodriver");` before calling `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

Comment: Update the question with the entire error stack trace and at which line exactly. Keep the relevant line of code trials and remove the other lines.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output: after setting the System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\HI\\Downloads\\geckodriver")

Answer (score 0):

You need to download geckodriver.exe and set your system.property() like this:

`System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path of geckdriver");`

if you are using latest version of Selenium you need to use geckodriver.

Comment: downloaded gickodriver and also set the property but it's still opening only browser not url......

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AzurePrice {
public WebDriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","Your geckodriver path");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/");

    driver.findElement(By.id("create-virtual-machines")).click();

    String[] options = 
driver.findElement(By.name("region")).getText().split("\n");
    //options.length;
    driver.findElement(By.name("region")).click();
    Select se = new Select((WebElement) driver);
    int i=0,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<=options.length;i++)
    {
        se.selectByIndex(i);
        driver.findElement(By.name("operatingSystem")).click();
        se.selectByValue("windows");
        driver.findElement(By.name("type")).click();
        se.selectByValue("os-only");
        driver.findElement(By.name("tier")).click();
        se.selectByValue("standard");

        driver.findElement(By.id("radio-one-year-987a88d8-f8fa-4b6d-956a-7c0db87f3b92")).click();
        String[] options1 = driver.findElement(By.id("size")).getText().split("\n");
        for(j=0;j<options1.length;j++)
        {
            se.selectByIndex(j);
        }

    }
}
```

}